# c# How to know the methods that are being run with thread

Tags: c#, threadpool

I´m uses a thread to show wait screen. User click on button process, system create a thread to show the wait screen and the process continue and i need to show the methods that the process has invoked.

```
public partial class Frm_Muestra_Consulta : Form
{
    private void Btn_Procesa_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Cls_Generales.Iniciar_Proceso(this);//calls the warning screen processing
        Cls_Consultas.Consultando(); //running process
        Cls_Generales.Terminar_Proceso(this); //Close the warning screen processing
    }
}

public class Cls_Generales
{
    public static void Inicia_Proceso(Form _Form)
    {
        Pantalla_Proceso = new Thread(new                
                        ThreadStart(Invoca_Pantalla_Proceso));
        Pantalla_Proceso.Start();
        _Form.Enabled = false;
    }
    public static void Invoca_Pantalla_Proceso()
    { Application.Run(new Frm_Procesando()); }

    public static void Termina_Proceso(Form _Form)
    { Pantalla_Proceso.Abort(); } 
}

public class Cls_Consultas
{
    public static DataTable Consultando()
    {
        //Methos to exemple
        //What I want is to tell the user when the system enters and 
        //leaves this method 
        Limpiar_Tabla();       
        Calcular_Espacio(); //and next
        return Realizar_Consulta(); //and next
    }

}
```

How do I make the yarn see or read these methods?

Comment: This is backward from how this task is usually accomplished.  Typically one would move the processing off onto the thread.

Comment: _"and i need to show the methods that the process has invoked"_ - what??

Comment: I believe that the OP wants a progress dialog that shows what stage the background thread is executing -- using "method" to stand in for "stage". As Sam points out, this is backwards -- you'd usually create the progress dialog in the UI thread and run the work in the background thread...

Comment: I try to create a general method to generate a processing screen. the process is in the general thread or default and in each screen exist a process that invoke the general method to indicate to user that the system is working and he has to wait. The time is unknow then i think in show the user in the processing screen (thread created in time execution) each that the initial process at begin and finished a method.
You know if it is possible and how to do possible?